# Xcode 7.3 "expected expression" build error

Tags: ios, objective-c

Not sure what is going on, I tried everything I know.... with no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction.

```
    [self presentViewController:messageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled)
        NSLog(@"Message cancelled");
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent)
        NSLog(@"Message sent");
    else
        NSLog(@"Message failed");
}

@end
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcFXp.png]

Comment: Try adding braces (`{}`).

Comment: Are you importing the MessageUI header?

Comment: 1) Fix the warning. Code should compile clean. 2) Maybe there is some hidden character in there. Try deleting those lines and typing them again. 3) Did you do anything to `NSLog` such as defining your own macro or something?

Comment: Cleaning the code then adding ({}) after the if/end worked! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While the open/close squiggly brackets aren't typically required for if/else statements, they do help clarify things.  And, there are instances (usually in switch statements), where the compiler gets cross-eyed if you don't use them.

So...Does the error go away if you wrap each if/else chunk inside squiggly brackets?

Comment: Got it, it worked after I clean the code. Thank you!